# CLRS Solution 8.4 example of decision tree

Tags: algorithm, clrs

Do you have an example of decision tree for this solution problem.

I want to draw the decision tree use in response to question (for most understand). But I don't know how to draw this decision tree. By example I don't know what the leaf is used for representation of this algorithm

Question 2

> Suppose that you are given n red and n blue water jugs, all of
>   different shapes and sizes. All red jugs hold different amounts of
>   water, as do the blue ones. Moreover, for every red jug, there is a
>   blue jug that holds the same amount of water, and vice versa.
>
> Your task is to find a grouping of the jugs into pairs of red and blue
>   jugs that hold the same amount of water. To do so, you may perform the
>   following operation: pick a pair of jugs in which one is red and one
>   is blue, fill the red jug with water, and then pour the water into the
>   blue jug. This operation will tell you whether the red or the blue jug
>   can hold more water, or that they have the same volume. Assume that
>   such a comparison takes one time unit. Your goal is to find an
>   algorithm that makes a minimum number of comparisons to determine the
>   grouping. Remember that you man not directly compare two red jugs or
>   two blue jugs.
>
> 1.Describe a deterministic algorithm that user a Θ(n2) comparisons to
>   group the jugs into pairs.
>   2.Prove a lower bound of Ω(nlgn) for the
>   number of comparisons that an algorithm solving this problem must
>   make.
>
> To solve the problem, an algorithm has to perform a series of
>   comparisons until it has enough information to determine the matching.
>   We can view the computation of the algorithm in terms of a decision
>   tree. Every internal node is labeled with two jugs (one red, one blue)
>   which we compare, and has three outgoing edges (red jug smaller, same
>   size, or larger than the blue jug). The leaves are labeled with a
>   unique matching of jugs. Solutions for Chapter 8: Sorting in Linear
>   Time 8-17 The height of the decision tree is equal to the worst-case
>   number of comparisons the algorithm has to make to determine the
>   matching. To bound that size, let us first compute the number of
>   possible matchings for n red and n blue jugs. If we label the red jugs
>   from 1 to n and we also label the blue jugs from 1 to n before
>   starting the comparisons, every outcome of the algorithm can be
>   represented as a set {(i,π(i)) : 1 ≤ i ≤ n and π is a permutation on
>   {1,..., n}} , which contains the pairs of red jugs (first component)
>   and blue jugs (second component) that are matched up. Since every
>   permutation π corresponds to a different outcome, there must be
>   exactly n! different results. Now we can bound the height h of our
>   decision tree. Every tree with a branching factor of 3 (every inner
>   node has at most three children) has at most 3h leaves. Since the
>   decison tree must have at least n! children, it follows that 3h ≥ n! ≥
>   (n/e) n ⇒ h ≥ n log3 n − n log3 e = (n lg n) . So any algorithm
>   solving the problem must use (n lg n) comparisons.

Comment: your question is unclear. what don't you understand?

Comment: I want to draw the decision tree use in response of question (for most understant). But I dont know how to draw this decision tree, I think with draw this decision tree I understand the reponse. By exemple I dont know what is the leaf use for representation of alghorithme. It 'is most clear ?

Comment: Example that i want draw : http://www2.hawaii.edu/~suthers/courses/ics311s14/Notes/Topic-10/decision-tree-insertion-sort.jpg